# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeespace' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-4: truncates \UXXXXXXXX espace

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как вывести в Python 3 изображение из файла в окне Tkinter? Пишу:

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()

image = PhotoImage(file="C:/Temp/1.png")
label = Label(image=image)
label.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

И в 3 строке вызывается ошибка:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeespace' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-4: truncates \UXXXXXXXX espace
```

Никак не могу решить проблему.

Comment: А можно текст ошибки целиком, вместе со всем Traceback'ом (если таковой имеется)?

Comment: Это и есть весь текст. Никаких Traceback не выходит, только СинтаксисОшибка.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Изображение в окно Tkinter](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/492065/23044)

Comment: Голосую за закрытие вопроса, т.к. на приведенном примере кода ошибка не воспроизводится.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, у вас не экранированы обратные слэши в строковых константах, например:

```
>>> 'c:\Users\...'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Вы можете использовать raw-константы для путей в Windows:

```
>>> r'c:\Users\...'
'c:\\Users\\...'
```

Неэкранированный слеш может иметь специальное значение в строковых константах в исходном коде на Питоне (`'\n'`, `'\u20bd'`). Обратите внимание на наличие `r''` префикса: `'\U0001F602'` это *один* символ (смайлик), `r'\U0001F602'` это *десять* символов (слэш, U, три ноля и ещё пять шестнадцатеричных цифр).

---

Код в вопросе не может `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape'` вызвать. На будущее: приводите именно тот код, который вызывает ошибку.